# Is there any difference in speaking and writing form for using "that"?

Tags: reported-speech

We use "that" in speaking and writing very often. I am giving some examples:

> I told him that teacher **is** busy *or*
> I told him that teacher **was** busy.
>
> He said that he **will** not do the work *or*
> He said that he **would** not do the work.

Which form is correct? That seems to me very confusing.

Is there any difference between speaking and  writing form?

EDIT: I am confused that which forms of verb I should use? would or will? is or was? Can you please give a guideline.

Comment: It seems to me you are reporting the speech, isn't?

Comment: Please check the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *that*s mark these sentences as 'indirect' speech, in which the speaker who utters the sentence reports the substance of a prior utterance in a subordinate clause headed by *that*.

The subordinate clause is conventionally cast in the same tense as the main clause:

> He tells<sup>`pres`</sup> me that John is<sup>`pres`</sup> busy.
> He told<sup>`past`</sup> me that John was<sup>`past`</sup> busy.
>
> He says<sup>`pres`</sup> that he will<sup>`pres`</sup> not work.
> He said<sup>`past`</sup> that he would<sup>`past`</sup> not work. (*Note that in this pair the auxiliary verbs* will/would *indicate future reference, but are themselves grammatically cast in the present-tense form. English has no future-tense forms.*)

HOWEVER—If the substance reported (the content of the *that* clause) still holds at the time it is reported, you are free to cast the subordinate clause in the present tense. For instance:

> I just saw<sup>`past`</sup> Bill and he told<sup>`past`</sup> me that John is<sup>`pres`</sup> busy right now but will<sup>`pres`</sup> be free this afternoon.
>
> I saw<sup>`past`</sup> Bill yesterday and he told<sup>`past`</sup> me that he will<sup>`pres`</sup> not work tomorrow because he has to meet a client.

Comment: In the last example, why didn't you use would instead of will? I am bit confused.  Isn't it  similar to the second example?

Comment: @RayanAhmed I am illustrating the acceptable use of present-tense forms in reporting a past utterance. Here the "not working" still lies in the future ('tomorrow') at the time you report the past conversation, so it's OK to use present-tense *will* to indicate that. But if you were reporting what Bill said about something that was in the future then but in the past now, you would have to use *would*: "Bill told me last Tuesday that he would not work on Wednesday because he had to see a client that day."

Comment: I knew that how twitter  worked, but I didn't use  that. 

Is it correct?

Comment: @RayanAhmed No; that sentence uses a different *that*, it has an ellipsis, and it has an error. Here's how you have to say it, with the part you can leave out in [] and the two verbs where you have a choice of tense bolded: "I knew [that] that **is/was** how Twitter **works/worked**.